# Special characters in html5 and ZK

Tags: java, html, zk

I am using a custom font set and some of my characters fall outside of the 256 character sets which are standard.

In ZK I am trying to set these characters as follows

```
lblOthers.setDynamicProperty("data-icon", "&#xe00f;");
```

If i enter the text '' directly into the  html it works well however through Java and ZK it does not convert to a single character.

Can anyone advise me please?

Comment: are you using awsome font?

Comment: no it is a custom font

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved by using

```
lblOthers.setWidgetAttribute("data-icon", "&#xe00f;");
```

Comment: Hi, I've a similar issue. In my case, I cannot apply a HTML special char into a bandbox placeholder from Java code. I tried the above solution, the character is applied to the bandbox itself instead of the inner textbox. Tried also using setPlaceholder and it doesn't work. Any solution?